# objective c: save image pixel RGB values to Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ipad, colors

I'm trying some experimental imagestuff on ipad and I'm trying to store every pixel's colordata into one array to increase performance for reading every pixel colordata,

right now I have a timer that calls my DrawRect as much as possible, in my DrawRect function I have this:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    [currentImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.3);  

    r_x = r_x + 1;

    if (r_x == 768) {
        r_x = 1;
        r_y = r_y + 1;
    }
    if (r_y == 1004) {
        NSLog(@"color = %@", mijnArray_kleur);
    }
    CGPoint point2_1 = CGPointMake(r_x, r_y);
    GetColor *mycolor = [GetColor alloc];
    UIColor *st = [mycolor getPixelColorAtLocation:point2_1];
    [mijnArray_kleur addObject:st];
    [mycolor release];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [st CGColor]);

    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(r_x,r_y,1,1));
}
```

and getPixelColorAtLocation is a custom class that returns the UIDeviceRGBColorSpace values of a pixel

with this it takes me about 4 hours (yes, hours :p) to complete one image, is there anything faster/improvements?

Thanks!

Thys

Comment: Not that I know objective C, at all, but it seems to me like your function iterates over 768 * 1004 values and thus draws that many rectangles. Guessing about 60 frames/second, this would take 3h 40min. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Made it an answer, feel free to vote up & accept ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Copied from comment for clarity]** Not that I know objective C, at all, but it seems to me like your function iterates over 768 * 1004 values and thus draws that many rectangles. Guessing about 60 frames/second, this would take 3h 40min. Am I wrong here?

Comment: yeah, you're right, I added a for loop around my function:

for (int k=0; k < 1000; k++) { ..... }

and now it only takes 10 minutes or so, thanks :)